# configure MSMQ cluster failover on an azure vm (windows server 2016)

Tags: windows, azure, msmq

I want to create a Failover cluster for MSMQ for two vm's in azure. I created two VM's in azure and have them domain joined. I can create the failover cluster with both nodes. However when i try to add a role for MSMQ i need an cluster shared disk. I tried to create a new managed disk in azure and attach it to the vm's but it still wasn't able to find the disk.
Also tried fileshare-sync, but still not working.

I found out i need iSCSI disk, there was this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storsimple/storsimple-virtual-array-deploy3-iscsi-setup . But it is end of life next year.

So i am wondering if it is possible to setup a failover cluster for msmq on azure and if so how can i do it?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a Cluster Shared Volume using Storage Spaces Direct across a cluster of Azure VMs. [Here are instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-portal-sql-create-failover-cluster) for a SQL failover cluster. I assume this should work for MSMQ, but I haven't set up MSMQ in over 10 years and I don't' know if requirements are different.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. We got it working with storage space direct!